# Only one texture rendering in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I was writing a graphics project in vs2013 it was going OK but then I had to revert back to 2010.

Now I've done that only one texture will render to the screen whereas before I had multiple textures rendering.

I have a background and a player. I load a texture to the background as so:

```
background = new GLuint(loadPNG("images/Background/Background.png"));
playerDown = loadPNG("images/playerDown.png");



GLuint Game::loadPNG(char * name)


nv::Image img;

GLuint myTextureID;

// Return true on success
if (img.loadImageFromFile(name))
{
    glGenTextures(1, &myTextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTextureID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img.getInternalFormat(), img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 0, img.getFormat(), img.getType(), img.getLevel(0));
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 16.0f);
}

else
    //MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to load texture", "End of the world", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

return myTextureID;



glLoadIdentity();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *background);
glPushMatrix();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(gameWidth, gameHeight);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(0, gameHeight);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(gameWidth , 0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();



glTranslatef(xMovement, yMovement, 0.f);


player->draw();


    void Entity::draw()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(m_X, m_Y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(m_Width, m_Height);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(0, m_Height);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(m_Width, 0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

I'm new to C++ but I'm just confused as to how it worked in vs2013 but when i changed to 2010 it will now only display one texture when drawn

Comment: I didn`t understand your code very well... Where "texture" (on function draw() ) is defined? Maybe this is what you should check...

Comment: Your code appears to be missing some pieces.  First, what are the data types of "background" and "playerDown", they appear to b GLuint based on the return type of loadPNG but then you use *background when binding the background.  Then in the Entity::draw you reference a 'texture' variable, is it filled with either the playerDown or background texture id?

Comment: It's fine the error was the else in my loadPNG() method

Comment: Next time you post, remember to put a sample we could execute in our side. It is hard to help this way - even harder if the error is in the method you didn't put the code.